# Updating a piece of data before app starts?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to edit a piece of my data before the app "starts" after reading [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/) it appears I can do this in created, but it errors with:

```
Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
data() {
    return {
        test: 'hello',
    }
},

created:() => {
    console.log(this.test); //should log hello
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an issue of scope (binding of `this`)

Try defining the `created` method like this:

```
created () {
  console.log(this.test) //should log hello
}
```

For full example see this JSFiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/u96L1maz/1/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions, this also will work.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      hello: 'hello',
      bye: 'bye'
    }
  },
  created: () => {
    console.log(hello) // hello
    console.log(bye) // bye
  }
})
```